# Get a less specific number - from another number

Tags: java, math, numbers, bit-manipulation

Right, sorry I can't think of the correct words to google this. So I'll have to ask.

I've got a `long` (`System.currentTimeMillis()`)

Lets say

3453646345345345

I want to remove the last six (or other number of) digits and I think I can do this doing some kind of bit shift?

so I would end up with

3453646345

*EDIT*

I wanted to get the `System.currentTimeMillis()` within a time box, so if I ask for the time then ask again 29 seconds later it will return the same number but if I ask 31 seconds later it will return a different number. With the 30 second timebox being configurable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To build on @Yob's answer, you can make the number of digits to remove configurable by creating a method like this:

```
public long removeDigits(long number, int digitsToRemove) {
    return number / (long)Math.pow(10, digitsToRemove);
}
```

Comment: so basically you are converting this to   a fraction and taking the mantissa . but because of the floating point operation don't we lose some bits ?

Comment: @Geek: Which floating point operation? Computing 10 to the power of an int won't cause us to lose any precision, and then we do a long division to get rid of the rightmost digits.

Comment: the long division is the floating point operation i was talking about

Comment: @Geek: The purpose was to get rid of digits, so this will certainly lead to loss of bits.

Answer (score 6):

You have to simply divide it by 1M `long shorter = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000000L;`

Comment: That's not very configurable though (where I said 'or other number of')

Comment: @Blundell You can make the divisor configurable any way you want. Can you give an example of what you mean?

Comment: So, put in a method with an `int numbersToRemove` argument and use `System.currentTimeMillis() / (long)Math.pow(10, numbersToRemove)`.

Comment: @Keppil you should put that as an answer!

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you want to do (in base 10, I assume), you can do this:

```
int64_t radix = 1000000; // or some other power of 10

x -= x%radix; // last 6 decimal digits are now 0
              // e.g: from 3453646345345345 to 3453646345000000
```

Or this (as in the previous answer):

```
x /= radix; // last 6 decimal digits are gone, the result rounded down
            // e.g: from 3453646345345345 to 3453646345
```

#### Response to Edit

For your purposes, you could change `radix` in the modulus example to 30000:

```
int64_t timeInterval = 30000;
displayTime = actualTime - (actualTime % timeInterval);
```

Where `displayTime` and `actualTime` are in milliseonds. `displayTime` will, in this case, have a (rounded-down) granularity of 30 seconds while remaining a unit of milliseconds.

To have a rounded up granularity, you can do the following:

```
int64_t timeInterval = 30000;
int64_t modulus = actualTime % timeInterval;
displayTime = actualTime - modulus + (modulus?timeInterval:0);
```

Though, based on what you are asking, it seems you just want to update a display value only every few ticks. The following will work as well:

```
if((actualTime - displayTime) >= timeInterval){
    displayTime = actualTime - (actualTime % timeInterval);
}
```

Pardon the C integer types, I just prefer to be unambiguous about the width of integer I'm using :P.